# Set a field value outside a form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

So I have a Rails app with a `Post` model. One of the fields is `collection_id`.

Each post should have the ID of the latest collection at the time of posting. If I have that ID in the backend, and I remove the form field for `collection_id`, how can I make sure this ID goes into the database without having a hidden_field in the Rails frontend?

The problem with a hidden field is that users could use a web inspector to change the value. This needs to be secure.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have that ID in your backend, you can pass it in your controllers action before saving:

```
   @post = Post.create(params[:post])
   @post.controller_id = variable_holding_the_id
   if @post.save ...
```

or in some cases you can do it in the model with a callback:

```
   after_create :set_collection_id

   def set_collection_id
      self.collection_id = variable_holding_the_id
   end
```

Comment: Can I do it from the model? Isn't it best to keep most of your code in the model?

Comment: you can do a before_save callback also

Comment: Which is the preferred method?

Comment: updated the answer. Instance variables are not accessible in your model, only in the controller and the view. So i think a callback is good when you are doing something that's not dynamical, but i guess your is so i think you will be only capable of storing it in the controller. How are you storing your variable?

Comment: But also, the setback of using it in the controller is going to be that you're going to have extra work if you are going to make some objects and store them in the database through the rails console. If you gave more code i could help you more